# Why in python kwargs are not counted as named args?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why in python you cannot do:

```
def foo(bar, *, **kwargs):
    pass
```

but can do:

```
def foo(bar, *, baz='qux', **kwargs): 
    pass
```

or in other words, **why python does not count `**kwargs` as named arguments**?

Comment: wouldn't that be the same as `def foo(**kwargs):`?

Comment: @MrFuppes does the revision make it clear?

Comment: Yes, I think you have a point there. Also, I don't think the dupe-flagged question explains this.

Comment: @MrFuppes, I also think the duplicate flag is not answering my question, but I do not think that I can do anything about that!

Comment: See [PEP 3102 -- Keyword-Only Arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/#:~:text=Since%20Python%20requires%20that%20all,must%20be%20supplied%20via%20keyword.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: in PEP 3102, is there any explanation to why `*` cannot be followed by `**kwargs`?

Comment: I'm late to the party but wouldn't `def foo(bar, *, **kwargs):` just be redundant? `*` forces the caller to only use named arguments after that point. `**kwargs` does the same thing but consumes the named arguments into `kwargs` as a `dict`. What reason would you ever have for doing the former?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Axe319, you have a point that address my question :D